# Exception handling in java - help me create & encapsulate exception classes

Tags: java, exception, encapsulation

## disclaimer

Hi, you could say this is a google-able question, but I've been looking around and all the examples I see are super specific to a certain problem, so I decided to just post my own question with my specific problem - some code here: http://pastebin.com/5ttK8Dry
(I don't want it posted because I don't want someone googling my code, finding it online, and think that I copied it from somewhere because this site will show up... please leave it in the pastebin. If it somehow gets deleted, I will just post it again immediately).
I hope you guys appreciate all my headers... :P Every time I use this site I get flak for having an unclear question, so I hope this one is very straightforward to follow!!

## Explanation of current code

The code accepts a user-inputted wind speed. It uses a generic try-catch block to stop an input mismatch exception, and uses an if-statement to make sure the value entered is within the legal range. (See pastebin)

## What I have to do

I now have an Environment class that has "wind speed" as a private attribute. In short, I need to create an object-oriented version of the code I have in the pastebin.

### What I know

I have to code my own exceptions and encapsulate them, and then throw them when I'm setting the windpeed in my main class - if I supply a value that is illegal, the program should behave the same as it did before.

### What I need help on

I don't really know where to start. 
In the code I have now, I see that I would need 2 exceptions - one for inputMismatch (which is already part of java), and one if I enter a value too high/low.

I know I have to code my own exception for the latter, but what about the former? That exception already exists...

## The ultimate question

(a) How do I create my own exception to be thrown if the user enters a value too high/low?
(b) How do I incorporate an exception that already exists into the process?

I can probably figure out the rest from there - I just need a place to get started.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html

Comment: This is confusing as hell. What does `if I supply a value that is illegal, the program should behave the same as it did before.` mean?

Comment: Change your profile and use your real name instead of user3225959. That way, your first concern will disappear, and you'll be able to post your code here, as you should do.

Comment: @the person who is still confused despite my many headers: if I enter the value "3&^#f" for my windspeed, it will print "3&^#f is not a number" and if I enter a value above 20 or below -20, it will print "the number you entered is out of bounds"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try{
//get number

if(number<minRange || number>maxRange){
 throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}

//Rest of stuff


}catch(InputMismatchException e){
 System.out.println("Invalid input!");
 System.exit(-1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! 

Would I be correct in putting that try-catch in my constructor for the "Environment" class?

Comment: Yes, I believe that's where it goes. The number would be a parameter of the constructor in OOP.

Comment: How to I let the class throw the exception? I know I have to write "... throws myException" somewhere, but I don't remember where it goes

Comment: You only throw an exception if the number is out of bounds. So you would throw inside the if statement above.

Comment: I know that, but I've written my Exception class and Eclipse won't let me use it. 

I thought I had to write "throws myException" at the top of my class or something to let it know that I would be using that exception

Comment: Oh yea, that makes sense... I'll look into it some more, I know I'm supposed to write my own exceptions, but I must've misinterpreted some of the instructions.

Comment: Awks. I just reread your question again. You don't need to write your own exception really. But if you insist, you would write a class that extends Exception. And any method that throws your exception needs to be written as: public void foo() throws myException{

Comment: Hm... that's what I had done, but I have 2 problems.

(1) -I get a message "The serializable class IllegalInputException does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long" which doesn't make sense


(2) It won't let me write "throws IllegalInputException" on my constructor

Comment: What kind of problem is it? Compiler error? Logical error?

Comment: the first one is just a warning (that I googled and some people said I can just ignore it)


The second one gives me a red x and says "IllegalInputException cannot be resolved to a type"

Answer (score 0):

```
  public class Environment {
private double windspeed;

 public Environment(double speed) throws myException{
    if(speed<min || speed>max){
     throw new myException();
 }


 }


 class myException extends Exception{

 }
}
```

Comment: my constructor header is - public Environment(double vw) throws IllegalInputException {

and IllegalInputException is underlined in red and it tells me it "can't be resolved to a type"

Comment: If you could post source code, that would be great.